# Java program keeps running: Telegram bot scheduled by ScheduledExecutorService keeps sending messages even when terminated

Tags: java, intellij-idea, telegram, telegram-bot, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a bot that first creates an array of messages and then sends those messages to a channel. The program uses `ScheduledExecutorService` and there are two `Runnable`s and two threads: the first thread populates the array, the second sends the requests if array is not empty. After a request a message is to be removed from the array. The message contains both text and a gif:

```
public class BotTest {
    private static final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
            Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final MyBot bot  = new MyBot();


        ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        Runnable createMessages =
                new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                      //...creating messages
                    }
                };
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(createMessages, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    //if (messages.size()<=0)  {                   
                    while (messages.size()<=0)  {
                        System.out.println("Array is empty");
                    }
                    //else  {
                    try {
                        final Message message = messages.get(0);
                        messages.remove(0);

                        bot.sendMessage(message);
                    } 
                    catch (Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //}
            }
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    }
}
```

`sendMessage`:

```
public int sendMessage(Message message) throws Exception  {
                boolean result = false;

                String linkText = rootLink + token + "/sendMessage?chat_id=@MyChat&text=" + message.getText();
                String linkGif = rootLink + token + "/sendAnimation?chat_id=@MyChat&animation=" + URLEncoder.encode(message.getUrl(), "UTF-8");

                int responseCode1 = new TelegramRequest(linkText).send().getCode();
                int responseCode2 = new TelegramRequest(linkGif).send().getCode(); 

                //...logging in text file

                return responseCode1 + responseCode2;
}
```

My computer (Windows 7, IDE Intellij) keeps sending messages even though I've long (hours ago) since terminated the process. If I turn off the Internet connection on my computer, the messages stop getting sent - until I turn it on again. What is going on and how do I stop it?

I also have logging going on: for each message an entry is made in a text file. However, no entries are being made for these continuous requests. It makes me think there is some caching going on and those requests were somehow put into some queue and only now are being sent...

Comment: Are you really sure that the VM is shut down? At the moment the program would run forever as your two threads never exit. By the way: Don't use an `ArrayList` for producer/consumer communication. Better use a `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: Is there any message limitation on Telegram? On Discord, you can't send more than a limited message number in a defined time. The next messages are delayed. Thus, your bot could send a lot of messages most of them being blocked until Telegram accepts them. And it could last for hours!

Comment: `Are you really sure that the VM is shut down?`, no? I mean, I thought when I click the process in IDEA and click Terminate, that's it... I tried using code from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Utilities/How_to_exit_JVM_and_add_shut_down_hook.htm): `Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(); runtime.exit(2);`, but the messages are still coming. I'm very new to threads, but now it seems to me that it works like this: when I terminate a class' main method, only the main method's thread stops running, while all the threads that have been created in main, continue their run.

Comment: @stevecross And now that the main has exited, there are no variable references neither to the SheduledExecutor nor to the threads themselves, so it's pretty much impossible to kill them? Though shutting PC down completely might help?

Comment: @stevecross  `Don't use an ArrayList for producer/consumer communication. Better use a BlockingQueue`. I understand that it's better to use synchronized or thread-safe classes when dealing with threads, but it looked to me like in this particular case there's nothing the threads could do to mess up each other or the array?

Comment: @Abrikot  `Thus, your bot could send a lot of messages most of them being blocked until Telegram accepts them. And it could last for hours!` - Yeah, I thought about it too. But then, it contradicts the fact that when I turn off the Internet connection on my PC, the messages stop coming. One would think if they've been queued by Telegram servers, they would now act independent of my PC.

Comment: > I thought when I click the process in IDEA and click Terminate, that's it..

Afaik IntelliJ tries to gracefully stop the process. Does the icon change to a skull? If yes, you can click on the skull and the process will be killed.